# Purpose of admin.py file in app in Django project?

Tags: django

What is the purpose of admin.py file in django project?

I created a app using:

```
python manage.py startapp app
```

This is the code found in admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
# Register your models here.
```

Comment: Did you try Google first? Literally the first result takes you to the relevant section of the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `admin.py` file is used to display your models in the Django admin panel. You can also customize your admin panel.

For more details refer following links

1. [Django admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/)
2. [Customize the admin form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial07/)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Django has a builtin admin interface that reads metadata from your models, such as fields, and lets you perform CRUD operations for free.

To be able to perform such operations, you need to register your models in the `admin.py` file

The admin app is usually available under yoursite.com/admin, but you can also change that in the `urls.py` file.